# Bootstrap: popover on modals

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I want to use the popover effect on an existing modals dialog using the Bootstrap CSS Library from Twitter. I bind the popover to the small image icon.

```
$('#infoIcon').popover({
    offset: 50,
    placement: 'right'
});
```

The modals itself is also added according the documentation:

```
$('#modalContainer').modal({
    keyboard : true
});
```

But the effect I've got is, that the popover is rendered UNDER the modal container instead OVER the modal div (see the screenshot below). How can I bring the popover truly OVER the modal div ?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The guys at Bootstrap identifies this issue as a bug and fixed it for the next release.
[see more details here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/383#issuecomment-2342782)

Answer (score 8):

You don't need javascript for that, simply set the z-index of the popover via CSS:

```
.popover {
    z-index: 1060;
}
```

Comment: This helped me because in my case it was the popover that was over the modal and I needed the opposite. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

In the meanwhile you can try:

```
$('#infoIcon').popover({
    offset: 50,
    placement: 'right'
});

$("#infoIcon").data('popover').tip().css("z-index", 1060);
```

Answer (score 2):

if you need to work on fly, you should be use

```
$("<style type='text/css'> .popover{z-index:1060;} </style>").appendTo("head");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check what is the [z-index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) value of one window and modify the z-index for the another one with a superior value. You can do this with [jQuery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function if the plugins that you are using do not allow this change in their input parameters.