# Twitter's Bootstrap Popover in Modal issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've been playing with Twitter Bootstrap for a while. Quite a nice tool.

Problem is, I've stumbled upon a situation where I need to present a [popover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popover) in a [modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modal). Problem is, the popover is show under the modal, as seen here: 
 [image: Popover]

This issue has already been featured in the past by other users (As seen [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/383#issuecomment-2342782)), but as I am using 1.4 version, it is supposed to be fixed by now.

Bootstrap users, do you have any idea on how to fix this? I'm using the compiled CSS, not the LESS-Compiled one, by the way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap: popover on modals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675203/bootstrap-popover-on-modals)

Comment: Yeah, and the link in the accepted answer is in my post. But, as I stated above, looks like that the problem isn't fixed in the 1.4.

Comment: Was your issue resolved? It's working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3v2zg/1/

Comment: In fact, it was. Sorry for taking so long to answer.