# Bootstrap popover 'stuck' inside a modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a bootstrap modal that contains information fetched from a db, and on each of these rows there is a unique reference, that opens a popover with closer information about said row.

My issue is that the popover gets "stuck" inside the modal, which makes it look, well, shait (see below).

[image]

My thoughts was that I wanted the popover to extend beyond the modal, rather than stop along its right edge. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Change the popover container to `body`, it should do the tricks. See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: That's entirely true, not sure how I missed that after reading through the entire popover part like 8 times.. Thanks! If you'd put your comment in an answer, I could mark it as answered. As a new user, can't answer my own questions yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the popover container to `body` using the `data-container` attribute or the `container` value in javascript. See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers.

Comment: Cheers - just as an aside if someone else comes along this issue, one more thing needed to be done - the z-index had to be altered for this specific popover, otherwise it would go behind the modal (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675203/bootstrap-popover-on-modals?rq=1)